# Interface Serial Modem to ttyS0 in AM1808 Embedded Linux

Tags: arm, linux-device-driver, embedded-resource, embedded-linux

I need to implement the Serial Modem interfacing with the ttyS0 port of the AM1808.

In AM1808 all these three serial ports are interfaced in following manner.This has been predefined in the driver of TI (**8250.c**)

```
ttyS0 : Normal Mode
ttyS1 : loopback Mode
ttyS2 : loopback Mode
```

Now i want to use ttyS0 serial port for GSM modem. For that I need to configure ttyS0 in full mode.

My pins requirements are as following and i have interfaced the pins as following.

```
UART0_TX 
UART0_RX
UART0_RTS
UART0_CTS
UART0_DCD (this pins are right now on GPIO)
UART0_DTR (this pins are right now on GPIO)
```

What i should do wether i need to change the driver of TI for the same ?

How i can do it ?

Guide me.

Comment: Yes i have done it. I need to change in the ***../drivers/serial/8250.c*** for that By default everything has been provided in the driver for modem control I only needed to assign the DCD and DTR GPIO pins to the UART driver.

Comment: Cheers! Welcome to StackOverflow. When you find the solution to your own question, it is accepted behavior (in fact you are encouraged) to post it as an answer to your own question. Feel free to add additional details that you deem relevant to the answer. If the issue is entirely resolved, mark your answer as "accepted".

Comment: Please let me know is there any way to put whole 8250.c file online  ? otherwise give me your email Id i will send you the whole ***8250.c*** modified file for that.

Comment: The focus is on having resolved answers, so that anyone who comes across your question on StackOverflow will find the solution to it as well. You can upload just the "diff" of your changes made to the file. Within 50-100 lines of code/comments is acceptable. Anything more than that one can always post on sites like pastebin.com and copy the link in the answer along-with a few lines describing your work(essentially what you have in the comment above). PS: I don't need the changes. i just happened to come across the question a little too late otherwise i could have saved you some time :-)

Comment: [8250.c file for Full mode UART0 configuration ](http://pastebin.com/95GdWbMq) Please go through the above link.